# TypeError: Net.connect is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

This is my code -

const mysql = require('mysql2');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({

host: 'localhost',

user: 'root',

password: '',

database: 'sagenext_web',
});

module.exports = connection;

this is my dependencies which I have installed in our applications

"dependencies": {

```
"@types/node": "18.11.18",

"@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",

"dotenv": "^16.1.4",

"eslint": "8.30.0",

"jquery": "^1.12.4",

"lodash": "^4.17.21",

"mongodb": "^5.6.0",

"mongoose": "^7.3.0",

"mysql2": "^3.3.5",

"net": "^1.0.2",

"next": "^12.3.4",

"next-i18next": "^11.3.0",

"next-unused": "0.0.6",

"nodemailer": "^6.7.3",

"react": "17.0.2",

"tls": "^0.0.1",

"tls-check": "^1.0.0",

"typescript": "4.9.5"
```

},